# JSF - Select a RadioButton and invisible an outputText

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, visible, invisible

I have a radio button and an outputText in my xhtml page.

I want the outputText will be visible, when I select radio button,
and OutputText will be invisible, when I unselect the radio button..

What is the visible/invisible tag? and how to use it?

Anybody knows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the radio button value in the `rendered` attribute of the parent of the output text. You can use `<f:ajax>` inside the radio button group to update the parent of the output text on every change of the radio button.

Kickoff example:

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.radio}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="one" itemLabel="This should hide output text" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="two" itemLabel="This should show output text" />
        <f:ajax render="output" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:panelGroup id="output">
        <h:outputText value="output text" rendered="#{bean.radio == 'two'}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Note that you cannot point to the `id` of the output text itself, because the ajax `render` requires a component which is *always* rendered in order to update its contents.

---

**Update** as per the comments you seem to indicate that you're looking for a client side solution rather than a server side solution. In that case, just grab basic JavaScript.

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.radio}" onclick="document.getElementById('form:output').style.display = (value == 'two' ? 'block' : 'none')">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="one" itemLabel="This should hide output text" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="two" itemLabel="This should show output text" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:outputText id="output" value="output text" style="display: #{bean.radio == 'two' ? 'block' : 'none'}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: thanks Balus but I don't want to render it. I want just invisible.

Comment: So you want to perform it fully client side? See answer update then.